# Issues importing with tf-agents[reverb] for building a DQN in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf-agent

I am trying to get my environment setup to train a deep Q network with TF-Agents. However, I'm getting a bunch of import errors that I can't seem to resolve. The tutorial I am following, [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial), required the following packages:

```
tf-agents[reverb]
pyvirtualdisplay
imageio==2.4.0
pyglet
```

And then the had the following big import statement:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import base64
import imageio
import IPython
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image
import pyvirtualdisplay
import reverb

import tensorflow as tf

from tf_agents.agents.dqn import dqn_agent
from tf_agents.drivers import py_driver
from tf_agents.environments import suite_gym
from tf_agents.environments import tf_py_environment
from tf_agents.eval import metric_utils
from tf_agents.metrics import tf_metrics
from tf_agents.networks import sequential
from tf_agents.policies import py_tf_eager_policy
from tf_agents.policies import random_tf_policy
from tf_agents.replay_buffers import reverb_replay_buffer
from tf_agents.replay_buffers import reverb_utils
from tf_agents.trajectories import trajectory
from tf_agents.specs import tensor_spec
from tf_agents.utils import common
```

I'm working in a virtual environment with python 3.9.6 on a Windows OS. After installing the packages above (with pip install) and running the above code, I was missing these modules (`ModuleNotFound`): matplotlib, reverb, and tensorflow. I ran another pip install for matplotlib, which fixed that issue. However, reverb and tensorflow were not straightforward. I ran a separate pip install for reverb (`pip install reverb`), but now the I get the following error on `import reverb`:

```
  Cell In [3], line 11
    import reverb

  File c:\...\env\lib\site-packages\reverb.py:64
    raise TypeError, 'Regexp cannot be negated'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Similarly, when I ran a separate `pip install tensorflow`, I was met with:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.

(traceback)

ImportError: cannot import name 'network' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine' (c:\...\env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\__init__.py)
```

I'm guessing that this import error is because tf-agents installed its own versions of tensorflow in ./env/, but I don't understand why python couldn't import them. Does anyone have any advice as to how to resolve these dependency issues so I can just run the notebook? Are there imports I should just omit, or do a different way? Is the problem with my pip install? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Reverb doesn't work on Windows (Only Linux)
https://github.com/deepmind/reverb

You will need to use a different replay buffer. `tf-agents` contains the `tf-agents.replay_buffers` class for its own replay buffer.